# Saving artificial sklearn data as an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to save as an Excel file the dataset generated by the following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import pandas as pd

X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy` to concatenate `X` and `y` then create your dataframe:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([X, np.vstack(y)], axis=1))
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```